# SMTP server not sending Email after registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, smtp

Why doesn't the SMTP in this code send notification to the email that has been inputted by the user?

Controller :

```
    . 
    using System.Net.Mail;
    using System.Net;
    .

    db_userEntities db = new db_userEntities();

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Regisration([Bind(Exclude = "IsEmailVerified,ActivationCode")] tbl_user user)
{
    bool Status = false;
    string message = "";
    //
    // Model Validation 
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        // Email already exists
        var isExist = IsEmailExist(user.email_user);
        
        if (isExist)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("EmailExist", "Email already exist");
            return View();
        }

        // Generate Activation Code 
        user.ActivationCode = Guid.NewGuid();

        // Password Hashing 
        user.password_user = Crypto.Hash(user.password_user);

        user.IsEmailVerified = false;

        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            db.tbl_user.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();

            SendVerificationLinkEmail(user.email_user, user.ActivationCode.ToString());
            message = "Registration successfully done. Account activation link " +
                " has been sent to your email id:" + user.email_user;
            Status = true;
          
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        message = "Invalid Request";
    }
    
    ViewBag.Message = message;
    ViewBag.Status = Status;
    return View();
}
```

and for the controller to send the email:

```
[NonAction]
public void SendVerificationLinkEmail(string email, string activationCode)
{
    var verifyUrl = "/User/VerifyAccount/" + activationCode;
    var link = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, verifyUrl);

    var fromEmail = new MailAddress("admin@gmail.com", "Test");
    var toEmail = new MailAddress(email);
    var fromEmailPassword = "********"; // Replace with actual password
    string subject = "Your account is successfully created!";

    string body = "<br/><br/>We are excited to tell you that your Test account is" +
        " successfully created. Please click on the below link to verify your account" +
        " <br/><br/><a href='" + link + "'>" + link + "</a> ";

    var smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromEmail.Address, fromEmailPassword)
    };

    using (var message = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body,
        IsBodyHtml = true
    })
        smtp.Send(message);
}
```

What is wrong? I've seen the other ways but I try to keep it the same SMTP doesn't send email to the user's email, the code above is the code I'm currently using

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine! It's seems that internet is slow. To prevent this, try to set a higher timeout limit. It is in milliseconds.

Try this:

```
[NonAction]
        public void SendVerificationLinkEmail(string email, string activationCode)
        {
            var verifyUrl = "/User/VerifyAccount/" + activationCode;
            var link = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, verifyUrl);

            var fromEmail = new MailAddress("admin@gmail.com", "Test");
            var toEmail = new MailAddress(email);
            var fromEmailPassword = "********"; // Replace with actual password
            string subject = "Your account is successfully created!";

            string body = "<br/><br/>We are excited to tell you that your Test account is" +
                " successfully created. Please click on the below link to verify your account" +
                " <br/><br/><a href='" + link + "'>" + link + "</a> ";

            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Timeout = 10000,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromEmail.Address, fromEmailPassword)
            };

            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body,
                IsBodyHtml = true
            })
                smtp.Send(message);
        }
```